# How to replace one word with another from a script using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a python script of more than 500 lines of code, this script is made in python2 and I am updating it to python3, in it I have a lot of `raw_input` that I want to replace with `input`, is there any way to do this directly in bash without having to go modifying one by one?

Comment: Yep: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html ; also `sed -i 's/raw_input/input/g' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to update python2.x scripts to be compatible with python3 is using https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html. If you want to change "raw_input" to "input" you can use `sed -i 's/raw_input/input/g' file`